# binding click event for dynamic element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div which is filled dynamically after calling an AJAX call by .html attribute

```
$("#gallery").html(imagesHtml);
```

insdie imagesHtml i ahve 2 buttons called "prebtn" and "nxtbtn" now I'm trying to bind these buttons with the following syntax in JQuery:

```
$("#gallery").bind('click', '#nxtbtn', function() {
    alert('next');
});
```

and

```
$("#gallery").bind('click', '#prebtn', function() {
    alert('previous');
});
```

but whener I click on one of the buttons both events get triggered and it shows allert for "next" and "previous"; howevr I have click just one of the buttons!

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: .bind doesn't support the event delegation syntax the same way .on does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) methods. They look similar, but `bind` has less functionality: it does not support event delegation. The second argument is not the selector for the delegated events, but a `data` argument.

This will work:

```
$("#gallery").on('click', '#nxtbtn', function() {
```

Comment: your code gave me the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @Pasargad In that case you're using an ancient version of jQuery. Use a modern one.

Comment: @Pasargad: What version of jQuery are you using?  `.on()` was introduced in 1.7, which is *very old*.

Comment: I knwo but lost of my stuff already dependent to the old version of JQUery; they are not compatible with the newer version :(

Comment: Use `.delegate()` for older jQuery versions than 1.7

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can use delegate in my case?

Comment: $("#gallery").delegate('#nxtbtn', 'click', function() { ... });

Comment: @Pasargad You've used the syntax @user1506980 provides? Because that shouldn't happen if you use `delegate` properly.

Comment: yes; now the error is :Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delegate'

Comment: @Pasargad You're using jQuery 1.3? Good heavens, there are some dinosaurs younger than that.

Comment: 1.4:D I'm trying to change it to the latest version, but I ned to change a huge amount of syntax too :D

Comment: finally after updating my  JQuery to the latest version and fixing some syntax error which was only compatible with the version 1.4 your solution solved my problem. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `.on()` instead:

```
$("#gallery").on('click', '#nxtbtn', function() {
    alert('next');
});
$("#gallery").on('click', '#prebtn', function() {
    alert('previous');
});
```

The `bind()` function will bind to the element in the initial selector, in this case `#gallery`.  So you're binding both functions to that event.  Technically that's also what `.on()` does, but it uses the second argument as a filter for the element which fired the event.  I don't think `.bind()` does that, I think that second argument is just data which your event handler functions ignore.

Answer (score -1):

you should use **on** instead of using **bind** to get it worked on dynamically created elements.
Whereas **e.preventDefault()** will prevent default action trigger of respective event.

```
$("#gallery").on('click', '#nxtbtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('next');
});
```

and

```
$("#gallery").on('click', '#prebtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('previous');
});
```